# Finding citeable statistics

Tags: graduate-admissions, citations, literature-review

I am in the process of writing a literature review as part of an application for a master's course and would like to cite Facebook as being the world's most active/ popular social media (or 2nd or 3rd happy with it so long as it is accurate).

Googling 'worlds most active social network' brings back multiple results from a variety of websites but no official press release of numbers from Facebook, or what I can see quotable articles. When faced with a problem like this:

1. Is there an advised, reliable way to find and cite the data? Only from a certain list of websites?
2. Is this fact so universal that it need not be cited?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facebook is a publicly traded company; see if you can find where they disclose active users in their quarterly stakeholder reports.

Comment: This seems like a basic research methodology question. Aren't those of topic here?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an advised, reliable way to find and cite the data? Only from
> a certain list of websites?

A quick one would be [Google Dataset Search](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/).

A more 'community'-led one would be [DataCite](https://search.datacite.org/) whose stated aim is to provide DOIs for research datasets.

If you need data owned by the public sector (governmental data), so-called *Open Data Portals* are the way to go. For instance, [this one by the EU](https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/home).

However, the whole area of research data management (RDM) remains underdeveloped. Thus, do not be surprised if you do not find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of citation ("so-and-so is the most popular website of its class" or "so-and-so has x millions of counts") is very common and I've done it quite a lot in my own research. It is very annoying (from the author's perspective) because it is tricky to cite, as your question indicates, and because the numbers and rankings keep changing, sometimes even between each major draft of your article. I have developed two general solutions for this kind of citation.

The best solution, in my experience, is to just avoid the citation altogether by realizing that it usually adds very little value to your article and so is not worth the hassle of figuring out the best way to cite it and keeping up with the accuracy of the ever-changing statistics. As it is, you are pressed to cite your claim because you are making such a precise claim as that Facebook is the world's most popular social media cite. Such a claim of being #1 indeed requires evidence to back it up because some readers might think that maybe WhatsApp or WeChat is more popular, so they need proof that Facebook is really it. But you could completely avoid the need for citation by rather saying something like **"Facebook is one of the most popular social media sites in the world"**. This falls under the citation category of "[common knowledge](https://www.google.com/search?q=common%20knowledge%20citation)"--it is something that everyone knows, so there is no point in citing it; it is even annoying to readers if you cite something so universally known. So, you just say that and do not cite it; no problem.

But if for some reason your argument depends on Facebook being #1, such that your argument would be invalid if Facebook were merely #2, then you would need to make that claim and back it up. Because such rankings change so rapidly and are almost never scholarly (indeed, the scholarly ones get outdated the quickest), it is perfectly fine to simply cite any [moderately reliable website ranking tracker](https://www.google.com/search?q=most%20popular%20websites) and mention the date of the ranking. There are [formal ways to cite websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20cite%20website), but because such rankings are not scholarly, I never give them a formal citation for this kind of thing. I simply cite such things in a footnote. So, for example, I might have something like this:

> Now I am saying something and then Facebook comes up. Facebook is the most popular social networking website in the world<sup>1</sup>. And I go on saying what I want to say.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_websites as of November 18, 2020

Comment: What does *one of the most/least [anything]* even mean? In the top 3, top 10, top 100? I'm not a fan of this phrase, because it's vague and an overuse of superlatives.